How to add environment variable when setting up for the first time (on local windows machine)
I am trying to run tests initially on my local (windows shop we are :-) ). When I am running the npx semantic-release its failing with the below error.
[1:54:32 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/github] » ℹ  Verify GitHub authentication
[1:54:32 PM] [semantic-release] » ✘  Failed step "verifyConditions" of plugin "@semantic-release/github"
[1:54:32 PM] [semantic-release] » ‼  Skip step "fail" of plugin "@semantic-release/github" in dry-run mode
[1:54:32 PM] [semantic-release] » ✘  ENOGHTOKEN No GitHub token specified.

Since I am running in my local, how can I add the env variable (GITHUB_TOKEN) and provide the necessary authentication?
Cheers!
I ran the initial setup on my local windows machine and I need help with passing an env variable to provide github authentication.
